# How do I build the following dynamic LINQ to Entities WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I need to mimic this in LINQ to Entities:

```
WHERE 
(title = 'title1' AND episodetitle = 'episodetitle1')
OR
(title = 'title2' AND episodetitle = 'episodetitle2')
```

I tried this:

```
if (title1 != null && episodeTitle1 != null)
{
      query = query.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(title1)).Where(z => z.EpisodeTitle.Contains(episodeTitle1));
}

if (title2 != null && episodeTitle2 != null)
{
      query = query.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(title2)).Where(z => z.EpisodeTitle.Contains(episodeTitle2));
}
```

But it's giving me this:

```
([Extent1].[Title] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~') AND ([Extent1].[EpisodeTitle] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE '~') 
**AND**
 ([Extent1].[Title] LIKE @p__linq__2 ESCAPE '~') AND ([Extent1].[EpisodeTitle] LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE '~')}
```

I need to change the **AND** above to an OR.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatenate it in one query

```
query.Where(
s => (
( title1!=null && episodeTitle1!=null && s.Title.Contains(title1) && s.EpisodeTitle.Contains(episodeTitle1) )
||
( title2!=null && episodeTitle2!=null && s .Title.Contains(title2) && s.EpisodeTitle.Contains(episodeTitle2) )
```